# what is the default type when a plain number is hard coded in a mssql statement?

Tags: sql-server, overflow

I have some code that

is doing

`SELECT * FROM table where col = 123`

col is `varchar(64)`

when col was containing values less than 1456324852868

it was working fine till at some point someone added value 635912311949815157 in the table which of course caused this error

`Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.`

This is because in order to compare two values they need to be in compatible types. So for some reason values less than 1456324852868 were converted fine but 635912311949815157 couldn't be converted.

My question is when there is hardcoded sql integer values (like 123 above) what data type they are and why it was working for varchar value 1456324852868 which is above int range but when varchar value 635912311949815157 was added things started breaking?

I did some experimentation and

`SELECT * FROM table where col = convert(int,123)` gives a different error (`Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`) so 
the answer is not int.

btw I know that putting quotes around the number will fix this new bug but I would like to know what is happening with the data types. I know it is a terrible practice but the code is there and I didn't write it.

I am using MS-SQL Server 2012

Thanks!

Comment: 123 is an integer with SQL implicitly converting `col` to an integer. However, the exact records that are implicitly converted depends on the chosen execution plan and therefore you may have gotten away with `1456324852868`

Comment: It will try to use an int until the value is too large for an int, then it will use numeric with enough storage to hold the value. This is fairly easy to test using select into.

Comment: @SeanLange then why 635912311949815157 didn't fit as a nuneric?

Comment: Because the longer value was in your table. When you query this using a shorter value it will do an implicit conversion to the higher datatype. So in other words. You have an implied numeric with 1456324852868but when the query executes it will do an implicit conversion to that datatype and the new value (635912311949815157) can't fit in that datatype. Does that make sense?

Comment: @SeanLange makes sense Thanks :) the process of implicit conversion is a bit greedy.. I thought it would try to get the biggest data type that is already in the table.. that is more cost-effective but error-prone.. going back to why this is a terrible practice :)

Comment: Well as you said in your original post, the way to solve this is to wrap your values as strings. That is how they are stored anyway so anything else is highly brittle and very likely to break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value 123 is stored as an integer, you can verify this in a similar statement using `sp_describe_first_result_set`

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT 123'
```

When evaluating your query, `col` will be implicitly converted to an integer, however, it will depend on the chosen execution plan which records will be converted and therefore you may have gotten away with `1456324852868`.

I had to debug a similar issue in our live environment. The query in question had been running without problems for years, until new data was added to one of the tables and the chosen execution plan changed. This resulted in failure of the query, because the new execution plan resulted in evaluation of a `VARCHAR` value that couldn't be converted to an integer.

Comment: Good point about the issues with behavior changing due to the selected query plan changing.  This is another reason why inserting or updating character columns with integer literals is a bad practice and ought be considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: So how 1456324852868 can be converted to int .. isn't that out of its range?

Comment: `1456324852868` would never have been converted to integer by your query, it would have been filtered before the implicit conversion occurs.

Answer (score 2):

For starters one should not be inserting hard-coded integer values into `varchar` (or any kind of character) columns.  **DOING SO IS A BAD PRACTICE!** All literal values inserted into a character datatype should be enclosed in single quotes.

That said the following code answers your main question:

```
use tempdb
go

select
    20 as 'tiny',
    1000 as 'small',
    33000 as 'medium',
    100000 as 'large',
    3000000000 as 'huge'
into #tempvalues
go

exec sp_help 'tempdb.dbo.#tempvalues_________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000003'
go
```

You will have to do this in tempdb and lookup the appropriate name for the `sp_help`

The result is that all integer literals are implicitly cast as `int` unless they are too big in which case they are cast as `numeric`

Comment: I know it is not just bad practice - it is terrible - but I didn't write it.. :)